# Chat to vs. Chat with

Tags: grammar, conversation

I work in an office and lots of my co-workers use the phrase "chat to", as in *could I chat to him about the project?* 
I would say the same thing like this: *could I chat **with** him about this project?* 
At first I wondered if it was a European thing (the people in my office who use *chat with* tend to be English or Irish). 
Is there a correct usage for the verb chat?

Comment: I've always thought that "chat to" was UK and "chat with" was US.

Comment: See also: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62591/chat-to-or-chat-with

Comment: Apologies, I mistyped. I meant precisely that: 'Chat with' is American and 'Chat to'  is from the UK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The prepositions are both idiomatic with 'chat' and are often used interchangeably, especially in American English. However, for those with a more poetic sense of language, 'chat to' is more unidirectional than 'chat with'. That is to say, 'chat with' conveys a greater emphasis on the bidirectionality of the exchange, while 'chat to' conveys a greater emphasis on the unidirectionality of the exchange. Taken to extremes, 'chat to' refers to a monological or at least more monological exchange, while 'chat with' refers to a dialogical or at least more dialogical exchange.

Prepositions generally take a semantic beating in American English as compared to British or Irish English.

Comment: Very well described, JEL!  The only thing I would add is that chatting with someone places little emphasis on the object of the chat, whereas chatting to someone may sometimes imply, rather weakly, I admit, that the chat was probably initiated with a particular object in mind. We were chatting about this and that. He was chatting to me about his plans for expanding the business. My comment is not a strong or reliable one.

Comment: Do prepositions generally take a semantic beating from American users?  Maybe we should call this place the "British Language and Usage" forum and the other place "Stephen King's Language Yard Sale?"